# TypeError: (0 , _react.useMemo) is not a function

Tags: react-native

*I try to use redux but I get this error which is on tittle.*

**I use like this :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class LibraryList extends Component {
    render() {
        return null;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
        console.log(state);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

*but this give me an error. what should I do. can anyobody help  ?*

[image]

**this is my app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './src/reducers';
import LibraryList from './src/components/LibraryList';

const App = () => {

    return (
        <Provider store={createStore(reducers)} >
          <View>
         <LibraryList /> 
          </View>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

Comment: None knows this issue ?

Comment: What version of react-native and react-redux are you using?

Comment: this is my react-native version :  0.59.1@arMedBeta

Comment: I updated latest version but it gives me still same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`useMemo` is a new react hook that is only available in the latest versions of react.  This error is saying that its not available for you, so to fix this, you need to update react (and react-native if you are using it).

The error should go away if you update to
`react` to `16.8.6` and `react-native` to `0.59.5`

See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24543 for more info

Comment: If it helped you, please upvote the answer @KhurshidAnsari